# Report DevExpress MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, report, devexpress-mvc

I made a report in devexpress with paper size A5 rotated, report preview in DevExpress is good.

When I click print in google chrome, the result report is different with preview in report DevExpress.

Any reason What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress XtraReport can not generate "pixel perfect" document for all exists platforms.
you need to manually tuning your report layout so it will meet your requirements.
also make sure that chrome printing pdf document, not html.